# convert string output of for loop into a single array in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to take my output from the for loop below and add it to a single array. The `list` object can either be `["envName-inactive-1", "active-1", "inactive-1", "envName-active-1"]` or `["envName-inactive-2", "", "", "envName-active-2"]`

**My code:**

```
if (appendVersion) {
  for (elements in list) {
    test = (elements + "-" + branch)
    println(test)
  }
} else {
  println(list)
}
```

**output:**

```
envName-inactive-1-v2
active-1-v2
inactive-1-v2
envName-active-1-v2
```

and

```
envName-inactive-2-v2
-v2
-v2
envName-active-2-v2
```

**desired output:**

```
["envName-inactive-1-v2", "active-1-v2", "inactive-1-v2", "envName-active-1-v2"]
```

and

```
["envName-inactive-2-v2", "", "", "envName-active-2-v2"]
```

Comment: @user16320675 I modified it. Groovy is a java compatible language & I noticed that a lot of groovy posts have java tagged in them.

Answer (score 0):

You desired format seems to be json. In Jenkins you have option to use writeJSON to convert list to json format.

```js
def branch = "v2"
def list = ["envName-inactive-1", "active-1", "inactive-1", "envName-active-1"]
def versionedList = list.collect{it ? it+'-'+branch : ''}
def json = writeJSON returnText: true, json: versionedList

println json
```

the same in plain groovy:

```js
def branch = "v2"
def list = ["envName-inactive-1", "active-1", "inactive-1", "envName-active-1"]
def versionedList = list.collect{it ? it+'-'+branch : ''}
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(versionedList).toString()

println json
```

result:

```
["envName-inactive-1-v2","active-1-v2","inactive-1-v2","envName-active-1-v2"]
```

Comment: I am writing a groovy script, Jenkins will be calling it, but i can't use Jenkins built-ins.

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your update. If i have an array like `["envName-inactive", "", "", "envName-active"]` is there a way to skip appending that value on any empty string? regardless of the element's location/order in the array.

Comment: so that if empty strings are in the array, it will return like `["envName-inactive-v2", "", "", "envName-active-v2"]` or like `["envName-inactive-2-v2", "", "envName-active-2-v2", ""]`